# Sproutcore datasources and creating new records with relationships

Tags: sproutcore

I'm trying to get my head around datasources and related models in sproutcore and am getting no where fast was wondering if anyone could maybe help me understand this all bit better.

Basically I have two related models Client and Brand, Clients can have many Brands and Brands can have a single Client, I have defined my models correctly and everything is pulling back as expected. The problem I'm having is working out how to create a new Brand and setup its relationship.
So on my Brand controller I have a createBrand method like so:

```
var brand = DBs.store.createRecord(DBs.Brand, {
    title: this.get('title')
}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000));

brand.set('client', this.get('client'));

MyApp.store.commitRecords();
```

So as this is a new Brand I randomly generate a new ID for it (the second argument to createRecord). This is calling my createRecord in my datasource to create the new Brand, and then it also calls the updateRecord for the client.

The problem I'm having is that the clientUpdate is being passed the temporary (randomly generated id) in the relationship. How should I be structuring my creating of the new brand? Should I be waiting for the server to return the newly created brands ID and then updating the client relationship? If so how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 2):

Right, after sitting in the sproutcore IRC channel and talking to mauritslamers he recommended creating a framework to handle all the server interactions for me manually.

So I setup a framework called CoreIo, which contains all my models, store and data source.
The data source is only used for fetching records from the server ie:

```
fetch: function(store, query) {
    var recordType = query.get('recordType'),
        url = recordType.url;


    if (url) {
        SC.Request.getUrl(CoreIo.baseUrl+url)
            .header({ 'Accept': 'application/json'})
            .json()
            .notify(this, '_didFetch', store, query, recordType)
            .send();

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
},


_didFetch: function (response, store, query, recordType) {
    if (SC.ok(response)) {
        store.loadRecords(recordType, response.get('body'));
        store.dataSourceDidFetchQuery(query);
    } else {
        store.dataSourceDidErrorQuery(query, response);
    }
},
```

Then the CoreIo framework has creation methods for my models ie:

```
CoreIo.createBrand = function (brand, client) {
    var data = brand,
        url = this.getModelUrl(CoreIo.Brand);

    data.client_id = client.get('id');

    SC.Request.postUrl(url)
        .json()
        .notify(this, this.brandDidCreate, client)
        .send(data);
};

CoreIo.brandDidCreate = function (request, client) {
    var json = request.get('body'),
        id = json.id;

    var ret = CoreIo.store.pushRetrieve(CoreIo.Brand, id, json);
    var brand = CoreIo.store.find(CoreIo.Brand, id);

    if (ret) {
        client.get('brands').pushObject(brand);
    }
};
```

I would then call into these 'actions' to create my new models which would setup the relationships as well.